# Issue making a div affect another div with on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu in the form of a ul. I want to change the color of the text in "account-username" to blue when hovering over the drop down menu.

I have tried the following, but it does not affect it at all.

```
.account-username-dropdown:hover a.account-username {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/s136ayq6/2/

**CSS**

```css
.username-panel {
  width: 153px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

a.account-username {
  width: 144px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  opacity: .85;
  z-index: 99;
}

a.account-username:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.account-username span {
  position: relative;
}

.account-username-dropdown {
  width: 154px;
  height: 100% auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  top: 0px;
  /*border-bottom: 6px solid #AD93C5;
border-left: 6px solid #AD93C5;
border-right: 6px solid #AD93C5;*/
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px #1d1e29;
  float: left;
}

.account-username-dropdown:hover a.account-username {
  color: blue !important;
}

.account-username-dropdown ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.account-username-dropdown li {
  color: #282A36;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .85;
}

.account-username-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #DAD9D9;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.account-username-dropdown li a {
  color: #282A36;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.account-username-dropdown li a:hover {
  color: #282A36;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.username-panel:hover .account-username-dropdown,
.account-username-dropdown li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-footer {
  width: 154px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1d1e29;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px 10px 0px;
}

**HTML**
```

```html
<div class="username-panel">
  <a class="account-username" href="#"><span>TEXT TURN & STAY BLUE WHILE HOVERED OVER THE DROPDOWN NUMBERS CONTAINER BELOW</span></a>
  <div class="account-username-dropdown">
    <ul class="username-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">1</li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</li>
                       <li><a href="#">4</li>
                        <li><a href="#">5</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="dropdown-footer">
                        <a href="#">a</a>
        <a href="#">b</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS code

```
.account-username-dropdown:hover a.account-username {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

doesn't work with the order of your HTML.

This way with the hover effect you can only affect a children.

So i added your CSS line with a small change to your code.

```css
.username-panel {
  width: 153px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

a.account-username {
  width: 144px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  opacity: .85;
  z-index: 99;
}

a.account-username:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.account-username span {
  position: relative;
}

.account-username-dropdown {
  width: 154px;
  height: 100% auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  top: 0px;
  /*border-bottom: 6px solid #AD93C5;
border-left: 6px solid #AD93C5;
border-right: 6px solid #AD93C5;*/
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px #1d1e29;
  float: left;
}

.account-username-dropdown:hover a.account-username {
  color: blue !important;
}

.account-username-dropdown ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.account-username-dropdown li {
  color: #282A36;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .85;
}

.account-username-dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #DAD9D9;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.account-username-dropdown li a {
  color: #282A36;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.account-username-dropdown li a:hover {
  color: #282A36;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.username-panel:hover .account-username-dropdown,
.account-username-dropdown li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-footer {
  width: 154px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1d1e29;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.username-panel:hover a.account-username {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="username-panel">
  <a class="account-username" href="#">
    <span>TEXT TURN & STAY BLUE WHILE HOVERED OVER THE DROPDOWN NUMBERS CONTAINER BELOW</span>
  </a>
  <div class="account-username-dropdown">
    <ul class="username-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">1</li>
      <li><a href="#">2</li>
      <li><a href="#">3</li>
      <li><a href="#">4</li>
      <li><a href="#">5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown-footer">
      <a href="#">a</a>
      <a href="#">b</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Changed the snippet so it really answer your question and removed the !important because it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hover effect to be on the a tag and set a defined height and width to the a. From there you can set background colour and also the colour of the tex5.